# Issue adding multiple web references

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asmx

I'm trying to add multiple web references to my web reference folder. However, everytime I add a new one, it creates a new localhost folder and puts the new web reference in there. So by the end of it all, I have localhost, localhost1, localhost2, etc... in my web reference folder.

When I add the new reference, I double check to make sure the Web reference name is 'localhost' but it seems to automatically change it for me. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you using Web References? You should be using Service References. Also, why do you want the name to be "localhost"?

Comment: "localhost" is the default, when you add a web reference to a web service on your local machine. I always replace "localhost" with the name of the referenced service.

Comment: Ahh, so its not a folder, but its the actual class itself. Ok. thanks M4N! Sorry, I'm going through training at a new job, so this is new stuff for me.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: "localhost" is the name of the folder in which the generated classes are put, but it is also the name of the namespace in which the classes (e.g. return types of the web service) will be put. To prevent naming conflicts between different web service references, each reference has to be put into a uniquely named namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` is what Visual Studio uses as the default when you add a web reference to a web service on your local machine. I always replace `localhost` with the name of the referenced service, e.g. `BillingService` or similar.

The name entered when adding the web reference (e.g. "localhost" by default) is the name of the folder in which the generated classes are put and it is also the name of the namespace in which the classes (e.g. return types of the web service) will be.

To prevent naming conflicts between different web service references (e.g. two web services returning a `User` type), each reference has to be put into a uniquely named namespace.